# Working around AWS Lambda space limitations

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am doing an example of a Simple Linear Regression in Python and I want to make use of Lambda functions to make it work on AWS so that I could interface it with Alexa. The problem is my Python package is 114 MB. I have tried to separate the package and the code so that I have two lambda functions but to no avail. I have tried every possible way on the internet.

Is there any way I could upload the packages on S3 and read it from there like how we read csv's from S3 using boto3 client?

Comment: Do you sure that you need more than 250 MB? It looks like you use some binary data. Which package uses so much space?

Comment: I am using pandas, numpy, scikit-learn and scipy. The zip file is 114 MB. Am i doing something wrong? How do developers upload python packages?

Comment: `numpy` and `scipy` both have `libopenblas.BNVRK7633HSX7YVO2TADGR4A5KEKXJAW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll` (40MB) I think there should be a way to only one copy of the file.

Comment: Try to move the file to project root folder and remove copy.

Comment: Ill try this @ADR

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can upload the package to S3. There is a limit for that as well. It's 250 MB currently. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Here's a simple command to do that.

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name FuncName --zip-file fileb://path/to/zip/file --region us-west-2

Comment: But my unzipped file is more than 250 MB and every time I upload a zip file into a lambda function then it throws an error saying it should be less than 250MB. and Where do I put this command?

Comment: Ah! There's not much you can do if it takes up more than 250 MB. You'll need to either break it up some more or use something other than Lambda. The command shows you how to deploy the deployment package using the aws cli.

Comment: Can I make my python file to import the packages from a specific path like an s3 bucket?

Comment: Nope, that's not supported.

Comment: agree with @MuraliAllada — you're just too big.

Comment: You have 500MB in your /tmp folder. You could download your content there from an S3 bucket, extract that, and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain limitations when using AWS lambda.

1) The total size of your uncompressed code and dependencies should be less than 250MB.

2) The size of your zipped code and dependencies should be less than 75MB.

3) The total fixed size of all function packages in a region should not exceed 75GB.

If you are exceeding the limit, try finding smaller libraries with less dependencies or breaking your functionality in to multiple micro services rather than building code which does all the work for you. This way you don't have to include every library in each function. Hope this helps.